# 'Awaiting recommendation' on Scholar One before any review process

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a manuscript to ScholarOne about 10 weeks ago. I'm aware of the typical workflow of a journal. There are two bullet points that have remained unchanged for about 8 weeks now - one saying 'awaiting reviewer scores' and the other saying 'awaiting recommendation'. From reading other posts, these don't seem to usually be said together - does it usually just say one or other? What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

The status that authors see is fully customizable, and depends on the actual workflow employed by the journal. What you are seeing generally indicates that there is at least 1 review task pending, and also a recommendation task pending. This is possible! For instance, let's say the journal assigned 3 reviewers, but only requires 2 to move on to the recommendation task. Since they are both now "pending", you could see both status's at the same time. Without specific information on the journal you are working with, I can't give you exact details on your situation. There are other possible scenario's.

Note: I am an employee of ScholarOne, but my posts and answers are strictly my own.